# Dayton 220 V motor wiring

Tags: motor

I am trying to wire a Dayton 1 1/2hp 220 V motor but I am confused as to where the black and white lines connect. I have tried connecting them to the P1 and P2 leads from the motor but that trips the breaker. I thought about connecting the white to P1 and the black to T4&5 but do not want to damage the motor.

Some advice would be greatly appreciated.
Ted

[image]

Comment: "LOW" and "HIGH" relates to the voltage you're applying. Then you can wire according to the diagram. Can u take a picture of the whole plate?

Comment: We also need to know where you are. Here in the USA black is hot and white is neutral for 120VAC (generally).

Comment: Thanks for the response, the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the label says to connect one hot line to P1, and the other to T4 and T5.  If one side of your 220 V is Neutral (White), that wire should go to T4/T5.

Comment: Thank you, sir, it works just as it should with the white lead connect to T4 and T5.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it "accepted".